# How to show $A\cup(A\cap B) = A$ using set properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having a hard time proving this simple and natural identity of sets. what I do is go round and round in circles:

$$A\cup( A\cap B) = (A\cup A) \cap (A\cup B)$$
$$= A \cap(A\cup B)$$

Now what? I apply the distributive property again and reach the first expression. How can I show this using set properties (distributive, idempotent, associative, de morgan etc)?

Comment: Hint: $A\cap B\subset A$.

Comment: Do you have the absorption laws in your toolkit? This *is* one of them.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I have done it by element chasing method, but wanted to use set properties instead. You mean proving each other the subsets of each other to show equality right?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What are absorption laws?

Comment: @samjoe: $A\cup(A\cap B)=A$ and $A\cap(A\cup B)=A$ for all $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  No they have to be shown!

Comment: First show that A is inside A (obvious). Then show that A∩B is in A and that A is inside A∪(A∩B), that is, inside A (again, obvious) and that it is also inside A∩B!

Comment: @DrHAL But that is still not using the set properties. Although it is valid proof.

Comment: @samjoe: The absorption laws are usually included amongst the basic properties, which is why I asked. Do you have the result that if everything is taking place in some universal set $X$, then $A\cup X=X$ and $A\cap X=A$ for all $A$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes they are in my toolkit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of some universal set $X$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
A\cup(A\cap B)&=(\color{red}A\cap X)\cup(\color{red}A\cap B)\\
&=\color{red}A\cap(X\cup B)\\
&=A\cap X\\
&=A\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks but I cant get how you got to second step $(A\cap(X\cup B))$ from line 1

Comment: @samjoe: One of the distributive laws.

Answer (score 0):

> **Answer 1**. Clearly $A \subseteq A\cup (A\cap B).$
>   For the converse, Note that $\color{maroon}A \subseteq A$ and $\color{lime}{A\cap B} \subseteq A$. So $\color{maroon}A\cup \color{lime}{(A\cap B)} \subseteq A.$
>
> ---

**Answer 2**. If $x\in A$, clearly $x\in A\cup (A\cap B).$
Let $x\in A\cup (A\cap B).$ So either $\color{red}{x\in A}$ or $\color{blue}{x\in (A\cap B)}.$ The blue means $\color{blue}{x\in A},$ and $\color{blue}{x\in B}.$ So in both cases (blue&red) we have $x\in A$.

Answer (score -1):

$A∪(A∩B)=(A∪A)∩(A∪B)$=$A∩(A∪B)$=$A$, the first equality using the distribution law and the last equality since $A\subset A∪B$.