# Need help understanding a proof for set theory Identity $A \cup B = A \cup (B \cap A')$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello guys I'm doing a statistics course and I am trying to brush up on some relevant set theory, so I can have a more thorough understanding of statistics. I understand the identity above intuitively, as the result itself it quite evident from a ven diagram. But what I have issues with is understanding the below proof that validates this identity.

Proof ( u: union, n :intersect, ': complement )

$$\begin{align}  A\cup B &= A \cup [(B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A')]\\ &= A \cup (B\cap A)\cup A \cup (B\cap A') \\&= A \cup [A\cup (B\cap A')]\\& = A \cup (B\cap A')\end{align}$$

The part that has me stuck is the identity : $$A \cup (B\cap A)\cup A \cup ( B\cap A') = A \cup [A\cup (B\cap A')]$$
I don't understand why the term $B\cap A$ "vanishes" , I have tried expanding the RHS to see if I can arrive at the LHS, but I still haven't found a way to do this. Can anybody offer me some insight?

Comment: $A\cap B\subseteq A,$ so $A\cup (A\cap B)=A.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show $A\cup(A\cap B) = A$ using set properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649320/how-to-show-a-cupa-cap-b-a-using-set-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \cup (A \cap B) = A$. To prove it suppose that $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$. Then $x \in A \lor x \in (A \cap B)$. $x \in (A \cap B) \subseteq A \implies x \in A$. Thus,

$$A \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A$$

$A \subseteq A \cup (A \cap B)$ is trivial, so we conclude $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$.

Also, one can make a more fundamental argument to prove your identity right away. In fact, this argument lies underneath all the identities you've used in the proof you provided.

$x \in A \cup B$. Then $x$ is either in $A$ or in $B$.
Suppose $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \cup (B \cap A')$. Otherwise, $x \notin A \land x \in B$. Then, $x \in (B \cap A') \implies x \in A \cup (B \cap A')$. Thus,
$$A \cup B \subseteq A \cup (B \cap A')$$

Now suppose $x \in A \cup (B \cap A')$. Then $x$ is either in $A$ or in $(B \cap A')$. $x \in A \implies x \in A \cup B$. Suppose $x \notin A \land x \in (B \cap A')$. Then $x \in B \cap A' \subseteq B \implies x \in B$. Thus,
$$A \cup (B \cap A') \subseteq A \cup B$$.